# Make Map Fragment Clickable

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an map fragment in my android application. What I want to do is make it clickable so that if someone clicks anywhere on the fragment I can start a new activity. I tried doing some research but all I'm coming up with is how to make map markers clickable or not clickable. My map fragment only takes up a small portion of my activity and shows only one map marker.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            startActivity(new Intent(yourActivity, nextActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you do it implementing on touch listener on map fragment view it will work for me, if click on map fragment u can open map full view in another activity.

may be this will be help u